# Performing PCA in Pyspark Returns Different Results each run

Tags: python, pyspark, data-science, databricks

Can someone help me understand why my PCA is getting different results each run?
Im working in Pyspark using Databricks

The current implementation of my code is as below

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors


pca = PCA(k=35, inputCol="scaled_features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
model = pca.fit(df.select('scaled_features'))
result = model.transform(df.select('scaled_features'))

print(model.explainedVariance)
```

If i run this code multiple times, i get different results for Explained Variance
The difference is quite small, but when i try to perform a K-Means Clustering after, the difference changes the result a lot.

Answer (score 0):

PySpark is a distributed computation system and relies on distributed versions of the k-Means and PCA algorithms.  In the distributed versions, they can be non-deterministic and have non-zero error bounds (see the links at the bottom) owing to the nature of data locality and a lack of a universal view of the dataset as necessary design constraints.

Each algorithm is designed in a way that no single machine has access to all of the data at one time to allow for datasets are too big to do so.  At each step of the calculations, local segments of the data are used to generate data for intermediate results which is then shuffled across nodes with available capacity.  Which entry is grouped with what other entry may change the results for PCA.  In what order machines are available versus which elements are ready for the next iteration is not easy to synchronize.

k-Means (even on a single machine) can also be very non-deterministic - it is *very* sensitive to the initial seed centroids of the clusters.  Making sure you always start with the same centroids can help (but if it is performed on PCA features that are changing, that will not help).  Carefully setting random seeds on each machine that so they do not collide is also something to consider.  Also ensuring that the same data is assigned to the same partitions  at the beginning of the run with sorting/indexes can help. All of these things together may improve the variance between runs, but there are a lot of moving parts that all play a role.

[https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ninamf/papers/distributedPCAandCoresets.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eninamf/papers/distributedPCAandCoresets.pdf)

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232063041_Principal_Component_Analysis_for_Dimension_Reduction_in_Massive_Distributed_Data_Sets